# IllegalAccess Error while accessing a method

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, access-modifiers

I have two classes.

1. Class A which extends class B
2. Class B has inner static final class, lets say C
3. This inner static class C has private method, method1.
4. Class D extends class A and calls method of inner class C and inject itself.

in more detail:

```
    public class D extends A{
        public static void main(arg){
            C.someMethod(new A(), args)
        }
    }


    public class A extends B{
         .....
    }

    public class B{

        public static final class C{
             private B fieldB;
             private static instance;

             private C(B inB, String args){
                   this.fieldB = inB;
                   this.fieldB.method1(args) // illegalAccess
             }

             public static void someMethod(B b, String arg){
                    if(instanceC== null)
                           instanceC= new C(b, args)
                    else {..}
         }

         private void method1(String arg){}
    }
```

With that code I am getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   B.method1(Ljava/lang...)V from class A$C

I do do not have any compalition error but on run time I am getting error. What is the problem here?

Note : Class B definition is in a jar file which is added as dependency.
Note : When I debug, when it calls C.someMethod it shows on frame panel as

```
someMethod 1253, A$C
```

should not it be like below ?

```
someMethod 1253, B$C
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. You are getting error because your method1() does not take any arguments but you are passing string. Also you will need  static someMethod(A a,String[] args) defined in Class C for your code to run.

Comment: it was part of code, just edited.

Answer (score 1):

method1 is a private member of C class which can be access only by Class C . You are trying to access via Class B instance , it throws IllegalAccessError

Comment: I was suspicious about that but when I tried same scenario with some little code I did not get same error.

Comment: You probably did something wrong against what @VNT said. If that private method method1() is inside C, it won't be visible for B , so there will be compilation error. If that method is outside class C but inside B , there should will not be any error. The way you tried to present your code and What you actually are using is probably not similar.

Comment: ok I have double checked the code and yeah I had forgotten one of the classes. And actually code looks like as edited.

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem has been solved, I cleaned the project and restarted and built from the beginning that it work. It seems JVM was messed up.